# "On-topic" question is duplicate of "off-topic" question, both have no answers

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, scope

A slightly strange situation. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30566749/how-to-configure-matlab-to-do-5kg-1m2-1s%C2%B2-5j) asks a perfectly legitimate question about doing something in Matlab. In [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28949740/physical-units-manipulation-in-matlab) someone asks basically for the same thing.

It would make sense to mark the first (later) question as a duplicate of the second (older) one, but that's not possible because the older one formally has no answer. It informally has an answer in the comments, so I considered turning that comment into an answer – so that I can then mark the first question as a duplicate.

However, the second question is framed as asking for a recommendation of a toolbox, which is off-topic. I shouldn't answer this question, I should vote to close it. But then what about the first question, which is formulated in an "on-topic" way; but the answer would still be to point to an external resource?

Deeply confused...

A related idea: Wouldn't it make sense to mark two questions without answers as "equivalent", so that if one of them gets answered, the other one would automatically become a "duplicate"?

Comment: If you say the question can be saved, you are welcome to do so. Edit away.

Answer (score 5):

I think the second question ("Physical units manipulation in matlab") could very easily edited to be on topic. You can then answer it, and close the first question ("How to configure MATLAB to do 5kg * 1m2 / 1s² = 5J") as a duplicate.